# Unable to use google_sign_in package with Fluter Desktop App on mac os

Tags: flutter

I am getting the below error while using the google_sign_in package for the Fluter Desktop project on mac m1. This error I am getting while running the project using the "fluter run" command. Can someone help in resolving this issue?

Flutter Version:  3.16.9
Dart Version: 3.2.6
google_sign_in package version: 6.2.1

> Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
> CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in
> repo update
> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "google_sign_in_ios":
> In Podfile:
> google_sign_in_ios (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/darwin`)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by increasing the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 10.15 (which is what the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package supports). This included changing the /macos/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file and its sister file Runner.xcscheme, as well as the Podfile.

Hope this works for you too.